# compute $a_1 + a_2x + ... + a_nx^{n - 1} (mod 10^9 + 7)$ using bash commands

Tags: bash, scripts

I am only starting mastering bash and have problems with understanding how to build the program for the following task:

> Input format: first number in input.txt is 0 <= x <= 10^9, then goes unspecified amount of 0 <=a_1, ..., a_n <= 10^9, all numbers are divided with new lines.

> Output the answer for $a_1 + a_2x + ... + a_nx^{n - 1} (mod 10^9 + 7)$

First of all, I can't understand how to read variable by variable, except using `$(cat input.txt)` or `$(head -1 input.txt)`, so I don't understand how to correctly input the variables. Secondly, we can't use dumb exponentiation `($x**$i)` because of overflow. Because of my scarce knowledge of commands, I can't fully comprehend how to solve the problem.
Can someone show me the problem's script with an explanation?

Comment: Really, this beyond what bash was ever meant to be used for. You would probably be better off using e.g. `bc` (commandline calculator), `Python`, or maybe even better; `octave` - google those.

Comment: You can use `read` to read the input line by line. If the numbers are going to be large, use `bc` for the arithmetic. You don't need to remember all the numbers, you can just output the formula and pipe it to `bc`, or count each `a_ix^{i-1}` directly and keep a running sum (will be slower as you'll shell out for each element).

Comment: Moreover, with the `mod` there's no overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
# Get x from first line in the file
x=`head -n 1 input.txt`
echo x = $x
# Get number of lines in the file
n=`cat input.txt | wc -l`
((nn=n-2))
# We will loop over i starting with i=0 so then x_to_power_i starts at 1
x_to_power_i=1
sum=0
for i in `seq 0 $nn` ; do
    # Show what we have now
    echo i = $i x_to_power_i = $x_to_power_i
    # Get a_i value
    ((ii=i+2))
    a_i=`cat input.txt | head -n $ii | tail -n 1`
    echo a_i = $a_i
    # Calculate current term and add it to sum
    tmp=`echo "$sum + $a_i*$x_to_power_i" | bc -l`
    sum=$tmp
    echo sum = $sum
    # Update x_to_power_i for next i
    tmp=`echo "$x_to_power_i*$x" | bc -l`
    x_to_power_i=$tmp
done
# Show final result
echo Final sum = $sum
```

That's just the polynomial, ignored the "mod" thing as I don't understand what that means.

Anyway, you can do things like the above to avoid overflow, you pipe things to the `bc` command (bc - An arbitrary precision calculator language -- see `man bc`).

Edit: here is another variant, looping directly over file contents instead of using `seq`:

```
# Get x from first line in the file
x=`head -n 1 input.txt`
echo x = $x
# Get number of lines in the file
n=`cat input.txt | wc -l`
# Create a new file with all except first line
((nn=n-1))
tail -n $nn input.txt > tmpfile.txt
# We will loop over i starting with i=0 so then x_to_power_i starts at 1
x_to_power_i=1
sum=0
i=0
for a_i in `cat tmpfile.txt` ; do
    # Show what we have now
    echo i = $i x_to_power_i = $x_to_power_i
    echo a_i = $a_i
    # Calculate current term and add it to sum
    tmp=`echo "$sum + $a_i*$x_to_power_i" | bc -l`
    sum=$tmp
    echo sum = $sum
    # Update x_to_power_i for next i
    tmp=`echo "$x_to_power_i*$x" | bc -l`
    x_to_power_i=$tmp
((i=i+1))
done
# Show final result
echo Final sum = $sum
```

Comment: Hello! It helped, thanks! But can you give some idea of how to make the script faster? Because of `a_i='cat input.txt | head -n $ii | tail -n 1` it's square difficulty.

Comment: I added another variant avoiding that line, see the edited answer above. However, if you want something efficient, you are probably better off using some other language instead of bash.

Comment: tip: `read -r line < input.txt` reads the first line of a file, shaves off a couple of ms.